# Facebook returns empty data attribute when publishing Open Graph action

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I am trying to integrate the new Open Graph [objects](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/define-objects/), [actions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/define-actions/) and [aggregations](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/define-units/) into our site.

I have:

1. Created an object and an associated action
2. Added the correct markup to my page
3. Verified the markup from #2 is valid in the [Facebook Debug tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/)

When trying to submit the action for approval, it tells me I need to publish the action at least once.  I tried doing that using the following request as in [the documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actions/):

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/<my-namespace>:<my-action>?<my-object>=<url-to-object>&access_token=<my-access-token>
```

The response didn't give me any errors but responded with an empty data attribute.

```
{
    data: [ ],
    paging: {
        next: "<paging-url-here>"
    }
}
```

I thought that perhaps the empty `data` in the response was indirect way to tell me it succeeded but when I look at my profile the action wasn't published, nor will Facebook let me submit the action (they still tell me I need to publish the action at least once).

I've verified the access token is valid, and in fact, I messed with it by removing a few characters and the request fails telling me the access token is invalid.

I'm obviously missing something obvious here, so would love some help!

Comment: @Blauesocke No it's a GET, which is supported via the docs.

Comment: hey TMC - I'm running into the exact same issue. Were you able to resolve it? I can't seem to locate your bug in the dev FB site.

Comment: @Henry I still am waiting for them to investigate it. The bug is marked as private as I gave them a bunch of information that was private for my app.  I'll post an update if I get more info.

Comment: @TMC awesome. ACtually check out my thread: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/10777793/unable-to-publish-a-open-graph-action-and-i-receive-a-weird-response  maybe you have the same issue? I'm resolved.

Comment: @Henry I'm not having the same issue as you. FB just got back to me tonight and they suspect they may have a bug with query string parameters. I'm modifying some of my code to see if that fixes it.

Comment: @Henry Turns out FB confirmed it's a bug and unrelated to QS params like they initially suspected. I ended up using  POST instead of a GET and I could post the action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook has a bug making GET behave differently than POST.  If you're experiencing the same problem I am and using a GET, switch to a POST and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

That should work. Please file a bug at developers.facebook.com/bugs for what you're specifically seeing and we'll investigate.

Comment: Thanks Alex. I've filed a Facebook bug with all the details.